# How to programmatically enter a new line?

Tags: android, utf-8, character-encoding, character, ascii

My app has a send email function, in this email I want it to say something like:

> Hello,
>
> This is an email.

My question is how do I programmatically enter a new line in between `Hello,` and `This is an email`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

"Hello,\r\nThis is an email."

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
txtV.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hello<br>This is an Email"));
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with ascii code? something like char(12)?